# python/jython how to modify only time value (23:59:00) on datetime field?

Tags: python, date, time, jython

We have field which we are getting in jython code with

```
date1=object.getDate("FINISHDATE");
```

I need to have the same date but  we need to set the time value of that date to value `23:59:00`

How this can be done?

Please do not use DATE.NOW method to retrieve current time, I need to retrieve field from the database which is usually in the future so I do not want to set statically DATE portion but only TIME portion

Thanks

Comment: Nothing in my answer needs to change due to your edit.  It makes no difference at all how `date1` is obtained:  both methods I showed will create a new `datetime` object with the same year, month, and day values, but with the time values forced to 23:59:00.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`datetime` objects are immutable:  you can't modify any of their fields, ever.  What you can do is construct a new `datetime` value, combining the `date` portion of your original object with the `time` value you want.  Like so:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, time
>>> date1 = datetime.now()
>>> date1
datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 28, 2, 8, 31, 655126)
>>> date2 = datetime.combine(date1.date(), time(23, 59))
>>> date2
datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 28, 23, 59)
```

More long-windedly, you could also use the `date1.replace()` method to change any number of the fields:

```
>>> date1.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=0, microsecond=0)
datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 28, 23, 59)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for comment but why are you setting statically those DATE portion values (28.10.2016)? Its confusing me... can you please show how to set statitally only TIME portion while date portion does not have to be NOW.

Comment: It works exactly the same way for any `datetime` value whatsoever.  Try it.  I used `.now()` solely as a convenient way to get _some_ `datetime` value to start with.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your efforts. Can you please tell me at which exact step I should replace your code and retrieve FINISHDATE value from the database since I am not sure where I should retrieve my FINISHDATE value?

Comment: Replace my `date1 = datetime.now()` line with your `date1=object.getDate("FINISHDATE")` line.  That's all it takes.

Comment: Hi Ti, I am getting this error: ImportError: No Module named datetime in script at line number 1 and my script is just like this  from datetime import datetime, time

a = mbo.getDate("TARGETFINISH");
a = a.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=0, milisecond=0);

Comment: Sorry, I can't help more - I don't use Jython,  Works fine in Python, and from the Jython docs it sure _looks_ like it should work:  http://www.jython.org/docs/library/datetime.html  Perhaps you're using an early version of Jython, from before when Python's `datetime` module existed?  (`datetime` was introduced in Python 2.3).  So you should at least edit your question to identify exactly which version of Jython you're using.